# Spanish for "douche"?

Tags: traducción

Is there a Spanish equivalent for "douche", as in the insult?

I've search and found several results which, while being correct, either are too regional or lack the force of the English insult.

Comment: Are you claiming that "douche" isn't regional?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I think he just means that the possible translations of "douche" are regional, regardless "douche" itself is regional as well.

Comment: @JoulSauron, to expand, I think "forceful" insults are almost always going to be regional. Either the force depends on some cultural factor, in which case the word either doesn't spread or loses its force; or it depends on shock, in which case spreading implies losing its force as it becomes familiar.

Comment: @PeterTaylor That's correct, I only found (or knew) translations that were regional, but JoulSauron, I get your point, that's highly possible. I've seen good suggestions here though.

Comment: Children’s slang like this varies too much not just from country to country but from one playgroup to the next for a definitive answer to be possible. I’d laugh if I heard an adult using *douche* as an insult. I don’t know a term in Spanish that carries the same little-kid feel to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some equivalents used in Mexico are: `pendejo` (literally means pubic hair, and it's kind of the Mexican equivalent to the Spanish gillipollas, and really offensive too), `cretino`, and `idiota`.

Answer (score 7):

The English insult *douche* or *douche bag* is an idiomatic expression.  As such, it is difficult to translate it literally.

A literal [douche](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douche) is a medical device used typically for vaginal cleaning, as during or after a woman's period.

As such, the insult is similar to calling someone a "sh*t bag", or anything else that might be considered unpleasant, unclean, smelly, gross, or disgusting.

The English word has the same Latin roots as the Spanish word for shower, *ducha* and they are close cognates.  The Spanish word for the medical device is also *ducha*.

However, this clearly is not an insult in Spanish.  You might get your point across, but you'd get some odd looks, too, if you used the full expression and called someone a *ducha vaginal*.

Comment: Being a native speaker, I swear to laugh for at least half an hour if someone use "ducha vaginal" as in insult. You could expect it perhaps in a very good stand-up (sounds very creative!)

Comment: @belisarius: I would laugh, too... if someone said that to me in English _or_ Spanish :)

Comment: @belisarius: But said in the right context, it would be a very colorful insult, indeed.

Comment: Can you give any insight on what sorts of Spanish insults might be more apt to be heard out of the mouths of children (including teens) than adults? I imagine this must be very regional, but is still interesting.

Comment: @tchrist: That might make for an appropriate question on this site.

Answer (score 7):

The Spanish equivalent would be something like "capullo", "imbécil" or "gilipollas", although this last one is more offensive/vulgar.

Comment: Capullo refers to a closed flower, gilipollas is regional expression (Spain) a term that I can think is "LADILLA" an unpleasant bug that attacks on the genital area (due to poor hygiene) Laddila is quite used in some countries in Latin America

Comment: in Spain's spanish, "capullo" also stands for "douche" , and "gilipollas" is an insult, not a bug.

Answer (score 0):

- *Capullo*. You can see images in Google of the cocoon.
- *Ladilla* does not stand for *gilipollas* is used in Spain only, not in Hispanic America. Douche bag is not a idiomatic expression ,is just [*ducha vaginal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douchebag).

Comment: Hello tamara, I have edited your post a bit to make it more clear. However, it still lacks some formatting and coherence. Take a look at [answer] and [edit] accordingly!